# I have a hyundai i20 1.4 fluid 2012. Engine doesn't crank

Tags: starting, hyundai, i20

At first the car had the problem with the key turning to AC only and didn't want to go all the way to ON and Start the car. I got the turning issue sorted and the key can turn all the way but the car doesn't crank at all. The cluster is ON as in a normal way when it is running 100% the battery is new but now I don't know what could be the problem please help

Comment: How did you fix the issue with the key not turning?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!